# Is one being penalized by using 'same_relation' (and possibly other library definitions)?

Tags: coq

Given any programming language, whenever a standard library function exists, we should most likely use it rather than write our own code. One would think that this advice applies equally to Coq. However, I recently forced myself to use the `same_relation` predicate of the `Relation` module, and I am left with the feeling of being worse off. So I must be missing something, hence my question. To illustrate what I mean let us consider to possible relations:

```
Require Import Relations.      (* same_relation *)
Require Import Setoids.Setoid. (* seems to be needed for rewrite *)

Inductive rel1 {A:Type} : A -> A -> Prop :=
  | rel1_refl : forall x:A, rel1 x x.   (* for example *)

Inductive rel2 {A:Type} : A -> A -> Prop :=
  | rel2_refl : forall x:A, rel2 x x.   (* for example *)
```

The specific details of these relations do not matter here, as long as `rel1` and `rel2` are equivalent. Now, if I want to ignore the Coq library, I could simply state:

```
Lemma L1: forall (A:Type)(x y:A), rel1 x y <-> rel2 x y.
Proof.
  (* some proof *)
Qed.
```

and if I want to follow my instinct and use the Coq library:

```
Lemma L2: forall (A:Type), same_relation A rel1 rel2.
Proof.
  (* some proof *)
Qed.
```

In the simplest of cases, it seems that having proven lemma `L1` or Lemma `L2` is equally beneficial:

```
Lemma application1: forall (A:Type) (x y:A), 
  rel1 x y -> rel2 x y (* for example *)
Proof.
  intros A x y H. apply L1 (* or L2 *) . exact H.
Qed.
```

Whether I decide to use `apply L1` or `apply L2` makes no difference...

However in practice, we are likely to be faced with a more complicated goal:

```
Lemma application2: forall (A:Type) (x y:A) (p:Prop),
  p /\ rel1 x y -> p /\ rel2 x y.
Proof.
  intros A x y p H. rewrite <- L1. exact H.
Qed.
```

My point here is that replacing `rewrite <- L1` by `rewrite <- L2` will fail. This is also true of the previous example, but at least I was able to use `apply` rather than `rewrite`. I cannot use `apply` in this case (unless I go through the trouble of splitting my goal). So it seems that I have lost the convenience of using `rewrite`, if I only have Lemma `L2`.

Using `rewrite` on results which are an equivalence (not just an equality) is very convenient. It seems that wrapping an equivalence into the predicate `same_relation` takes away this convenience. Was I right to follow my instinct and force myself to use `same_relation`? More generally, is it so true that if a construct is defined in the standard Coq library, I should use it, rather than define my own version of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pose two questions, I try to answer separately:

- Regarding your rewrite problem, this problem is natural as the definition of `same_relation` goes as double inclusion. I agree that maybe a definition using `iff`  would be more convenient. It would really depend on the kind of goals you have. A possible solution for your problem is to define a view:

  ```
  Lemma L1 {A:Type} {x y:A} : rel1 x y <-> rel2 x y.
  Proof.
  Admitted.

  Lemma L2 {A:Type} : same_relation A rel1 rel2.
  Proof.
  Admitted.

  Lemma U {T} {R1 R2 : relation T} :
    same_relation _ R1 R2 -> forall x y, R1 x y <-> R2 x y.
  Proof. now destruct 1; intros x y; split; auto. Qed.

  Lemma application2 {A:Type} {x y:A} {p:Prop} :
     p /\ rel1 x y -> p /\ rel2 x y.
  Proof. now rewrite (U L2). Qed.
  ```

  Note also that rewriting with a `<->` relation is not really based on equality, but on "setoid rewriting". In fact, the following doesn't hold in Coq `A <-> B -> A = B`.
- Regarding your second question, whether to use the Coq standard library is a highly subjective topic. I personally rarely use it, I prefer a different library called `math-comp`, but YMMV. Regarding relations, mathcomp is mostly specialized into boolean relations `rel x y = x -> y -> bool`, thus, equivalence is simply defined as equality, typically, given `r1 r2` you'd write `r1 =2 r2`.

  IMHO in the end, such choices are highly dependent on your application domain.

**[edit]**: Note that the Relation library is dated:

> Naive set theory in Coq. Coq V6.1. This work was started in July 1993 by F. Prost.

So indeed, it may not be the best modern base to build Coq developments on.

Comment: Thanks very much !!

Comment: The `Sets` library (which contains `Relation` with capital `R`) was started in 1993. But the OP refers to the `Relations` library that contains `relation` (I don't know when it was started, though).

Comment: I think `Relations` are a direct descendant of `Sets` but the svn history doesn't go as far in an easy way.